# Como executar projetos Android, no Eclipse, em um smartphone?

Tags: android, eclipse

Tenho um Moto G e, de jeito nenhum, estou conseguindo conectá-lo (via USB) ao Eclipse, para executar os projetos *Android Application* diretamente no dispositivo.

Comment: Ele está liberado para debug? Na parte de configurações > desenvolvimento?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deixou a opção depuração de USB marcada no Moto G?

Depois é só rodar no dispositivo.

Comment: É isso mesmo. Depuração via USB desativada! O que acontece é o que o Moto G vem com essa opção (configurações > desenvolvimento) "escondida", e eu não tava encontrando.

No site da Motorola, descobri que pra liberá-la é preciso ir até "**Configurações > Sobre o telefone**", e dar 7 toques seguidos em "Número da versão".

Tudo Certo =)

Comment: Que bom que conseguiu @rafaelnep

Comment: Isso não é só em celulares Motorola, é coisa do Android Jellybean 4.2 e acima. Pode até mudar o título da questão especificando isso se quiser.

Comment: Boa informação, @Piovezan. É apenas o meu primeiro smart com Android, então nem tenho muito prática com a plataforma, de um modo geral. De fato, A versão do meu sistema é a 4.3. Vlw

Answer (score 6):

Tente o seguinte:

- Habilite a Depuração via USB no seu smartphone.
- Instale o driver dele no PC (alguns só funcionam assim).
- Se tiver que instalar driver, reinicie o Eclipse.

---

Para ter certeza se o SDK está detectando o aparelho execute o seguinte:

```
cd <dir_do_seu_sdk>
cd platform-tools
adb devices
```

Se o aparelho foi detectado, ele será mostrado numa lista tipo essa:

```
List of devices attached
c0808d70a7a9730 device
```